# Cannot access struts action data from nested JSP

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, html, struts2

I am working for first time with Struts 2 + Spring + Hibernate architecture. I took this [project](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-hibernate-integration-example/) as reference for building it and it works. I can list DB tables in my index.jsp using struts tags, but this does not work from nested JSP loaded into DIV containers inside index.jsp.

index.jsp has a `<div class="art-nav"></div>` and loads there another jsp using js:

```
    $(".art-nav").load("./menu.jsp");
```

The same struts tags that work in index.jsp to list DB tables do not work in menu.jsp. I am not sure if the problem is the way I am loading this JSP or if it is necessary to execute some action from Struts 2 before loading menu.jsp...

Basically the JSPs use AJAX and I am adapting them to this architecture and there is where I am facing the problems because of my lack of experience.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: not very sure how Jquery execute this, but yes in order for S2 tag to work it should go through proper request cycle to init value stack and other required S2 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the second jsp as follows:

```
<div class="art-nav">    
    <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp"%>
</div>
```

If you load your jsp via javascript the response will not get forwarded to that jsp.

If you really want to load a jsp via javascript you should create a new action (menu.action) that returns a parsed jsp and include it in the existing html.  (Though I personally do not really like that technique.)

Comment: I tried the import but it makes no difference...Just to clarify: the second JSP is correctly loaded, but the struts tags cannot access the data. What about using struts-jquery tags? Would this make a difference?

Comment: I added the div in the example.  To be clear, you don't import the jsp in the JS block but in the actual html part of your page.

Comment: It worked! But now, can I refresh/reload the DIV contents as I was doing now with `$(".art-nav").load("./menu.jsp")`? And can I load a different JSP in the same DIV?

Comment: You can load different jsp's if you want but reloading the content of div like this is not possible.  If you do it this way you have to reload the entire page.  To reload the contents of a div you should have a menu.action action and do what you initially thought of doing.  But this was not stated in the question.